# Popover in Bootstrap3 - how to make it not dismissive on content click

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to make my popover **not dissmisive** on content click while using focus trigger, because I have input inside in it.

Here are my div attributes:

```
data-toggle="popover" data-content="<input type='text' class='form-control'><button class='btn btn-sm btn-default' style='margin-top:5px'>Zapisz</button>" data-title="Description" data-html="true" data-trigger="focus" data-container="body"
```

So as you can see I have simple popover which is triggered with focus ( I know that it may be the issue why it is closing on click) but I have to close popover on click somewhere else on the screen that's why I'm using the `trigger="focus"`.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a listener (`hide.bs.popover`) to the popover and prevent execution of the event. In this case you need to add further listener to manually close it on button click. Something like this should work.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({html: true});  

    $("[data-toggle='popover']").on('hide.bs.popover', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    $("[data-toggle='popover']").on('shown.bs.popover', function(e)
    {
        // create your own listener after popover has shown
        $("#your_button").on('click', function(e){
            $("[data-toggle='popover']").off('hide.bs.popover');
            $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover('hide');
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

I hope it helps.